# BeanTreeView: how to display the properties of the selected tree item in the native "Properties" window?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I need to use BeanTreeView for my project, so I practiced using this component in this guide:
[Tutorial](https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/tutorials/nbm-selection-2/)

Here is the complete source code:
[Source code](https://github.com/bradh/NetBeansSelection2)

I would like to display the properties of the selected tree item (Event) in the native "Properties" window, which this line of code should provide:
`associateLookup(ExplorerUtils.createLookup(mgr, getActionMap()));`

Unfortunately, the properties of the selected tree item are not displayed in "Properties" window, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another tutorial that describes what you need:

https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2/#_creating_a_node_subclass

and

https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2/#_properties_and_the_property_sheet

You basically have to make a few changes in the "My Editor" project.

Introduce a new class `EventNode`:

```
package org.myorg.myeditor;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import org.myorg.myapi.Event;
import org.openide.ErrorManager;
import org.openide.nodes.AbstractNode;
import org.openide.nodes.Children;
import org.openide.nodes.PropertySupport;
import org.openide.nodes.Sheet;
import org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups;

public class EventNode extends AbstractNode {

    public EventNode(Event obj) {
        super(Children.create(new EventChildFactory(), true), Lookups.singleton(obj));
        setDisplayName("Event " + obj.getIndex());
    }

    public EventNode() {
        super(Children.create(new EventChildFactory(), true));
        setDisplayName("Root");
    }

    @Override
    protected Sheet createSheet() {
        Sheet sheet = Sheet.createDefault();
        Sheet.Set set = Sheet.createPropertiesSet();
        Event obj = getLookup().lookup(Event.class);

        try {
            Property indexProp = new PropertySupport.Reflection(obj, Integer.class, "getIndex", null);
            Property dateProp = new PropertySupport.Reflection(obj, ZonedDateTime.class, "getDate", null);

            indexProp.setName("index");
            dateProp.setName("date");

            set.put(indexProp);
            set.put(dateProp);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            ErrorManager.getDefault();
        }

        sheet.put(set);
        return sheet;
    }
}
```

Change the constructor of `MyEditor`:

```
public MyEditor() {
    initComponents();
    Event obj = new Event();
    associateLookup(ExplorerUtils.createLookup(mgr, getActionMap()));

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new BeanTreeView(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDisplayName("MyEditor " + obj.getIndex());
//        mgr.setRootContext(new AbstractNode(Children.create(new EventChildFactory(), true))); // remove this line
    mgr.setRootContext(new EventNode());    // and add this one instead
}
```

And in `EventChildFactory` alter the `createNodeForKey` method:

```
@Override
protected Node createNodeForKey(Event key) {
    return new EventNode(key);
}
```